# Vertex array is not being drawn

Tags: c, opengl

I have a vertex array that has 8 vertices, every vertex is represented by two coordinates.
I have used `glVertexPointer` function to use this array in drawing with `glDrawArray` function.

```
void datasource()
{
    GLfloat vertex1[]={ -1.000000, 0.500000, -0.700000, 0.500000, -1.000000, 0.800000, -0.700000, 0.800000, -0.400000, 0.500000, -0.100000, 0.500000, -0.400000, 0.800000, -0.100000, 0.800000 };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertex1);
}

void display()
{
    frame++;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

When I try to draw line using first two vertices, I do not see anything but it should appear horizontal line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `glVertexPointer` is deprecated, you should use `glVertexAttrib` instead.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Only if OP is using a OpenGL-3 context or later.

Comment: @datenwolf Using this logic, we cannot say *anything* is deprecated, since OP could be using 1.1

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: If OP does not use shaders, which is likely the case, then glVertexAttrib won't work anyway (unless one assumes the mapping of OpenGL-2 default attribute locations to fixed function vertex attributes).

Comment: @datenwolf It works also in 4.3 in compatibility mode. (for example, 0 is position by default).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Well, OP may be using OpenGL-1.1 (it has vertex arrays) and glVertexAttribPointer not available at all. Anyway, it's not the cause of his problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your data is on the stack of a function, you probably call to set the array pointer. Unfortunately as soon as the function returns it's stack frame gets deallocated and that pointer becomes invalid.

So either use a VBO to copy that data to a persistent OpenGL object first. Or allocate that memory on the heap or as a global variable.

Also you should call `glEnableClientState` and `glVertexPointer` *right before* the corresponding `glDraw…` function call.

Comment: Thank you very much , it works when I make the `vertex1` as global variable

Comment: @user1841718, it would be nice of you to accept helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `glVertexPointer` function every time, when you call `display` function

Comment: This won't help with the fact that `vertex1` is on the stack of `datasource` and gets invalid as soon as `datasource` returns.